# Django Unknown system variable 'TRANSACTION' on syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

My local Django is blowing up running the manage.py syncdb script that runs on our servers.

This is the error message I'm seeing when running `python manage.py syncdb`,

> OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'TRANSACTION'")

It looks like a MySQL issue, just for reference I have MySQL-python 1.2.4 install with Django 1.5.1 in a virtual env and I am running MySQL version 5.6.10.

This is my current virtual env in full from `pip list`,

```
Django (1.5.1)
MySQL-python (1.2.4)
pymongo (2.5.2)
python-cjson (1.0.5)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

I'm not very proficient with Django and Googling has turned up nothing, could anyone tell me what might be going here?

Full trackback of the command below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 56, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 326, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 405, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jamesmcmahon/src/business-intelligence/mongo2mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'TRANSACTION'")
```

**EDIT:**
I found the exact line causing the issues, in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'NAME': 'test',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'redacted',
        'PASSWORD': 'redacted',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
        'OPTIONS': { "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" }
    },
}
```

The options line, when committed out, fixes the issue. Only thing I can think of is that the server is running MySQL 5.5 and I am running 5.6 locally.

I'd still like to figure out exactly what is going on.

Comment: Could you try to reinstall django first? Any changes?

Comment: @alecxe what do you mean by reinstall? `pip uninstall` and then `pip install`?

Comment: Yup, exactly. The idea is that the problem is caused by installing different django versions on top of each other.

Comment: Yeah tried that, no luck :( I'm running in venv to prevent issues like that.

Comment: Yeah, right, looks like mysql issue. What mysql version are you using? Additionally, could you please include full error traceback?

Answer (score 6):

use

> DATABASES = {
>
> > ```
> > 'default': {
> >     'NAME': 'test',
> >     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
> >     'USER': 'redacted',
> >     'PASSWORD': 'redacted',
> >     'HOST': 'localhost'
> >     'OPTIONS': { "init_command": "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"}
> > ```
> >
> > },
>
> }

ie without "storage_engine=INNODB,". The latest versions of MySql engine by default INNODB.

Comment: Thanks, I probably won't get a chance to try this for a little since I am occupied by other things at work, but I will make of this and check it out in the future.

Comment: I think the problem is related to passing multiple values in the init_command. I'm seeing similar error when trying do to `SET NAMES utf8,SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL read committed`

Answer (score 0):

- Check your mysql version by running `sudo mysqld --version`
- In mysql version 5.7.11, the storage engine system variable is: `default-storege-engine` therefore, your `OPTIONS` settings should be:

   `{
      'OPTIONS': { "init_command": "SET default_storage_engine=INNODB"}
   }`
- To find the name of the storage engine variable on your system, run this command `sudo mysqld --verbose --help | grep storage`